# Sending and receiving protobuf data over Socket via boost asio

Tags: c++, tcp, protocol-buffers, boost-asio

I want to send Protobuf data from my server to my client thanks to a TCP socket.

I tested my client and my server and the TCP connexion works.

So I try to serialize my data and send it by using a streambuf.

In my server :

```
void SendData(protobufType data){
        std::ostream ostream(&this->m_streambuf);
        data.SerializeToOstream(&ostream);

        std::cout<<"Send data"<< std::endl;
        boost::asio::write(this->m_socket, this->m_streambuf);
}
```

In my client :

```
boost::asio::streambuf response;
boost::asio::read(socket, response);
std::cout<<"Data received"<< std::endl;
```

I run 3 times my send function (I guess my data seams to be sent) but myclient seams to never get data ...

Answer (score 0):

Your client hangs on this line

```
boost::asio::read(socket, response);
```

because above is the same as

```
boost::asio::read(socket, response, boost::asio::tranfer_all());
```

what is described in [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload9.html).

You use `read` overload which takes completion condition. There are three kinds of these functors: `transfer_all_t`, `transfer_exactly_t` and `transfer_at_least_t`. Each of them has `operator()()` which returns 0 if read operation is completion - [see reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/CompletionCondition.html).

The code for `transfer_all_t::opeator()()` is:

```
  template <typename Error>
  std::size_t operator()(const Error& err, std::size_t)
  {
    return !!err ? 0 : default_max_transfer_size;
  }
```

so 0 is returned only if an error occurres.

`transfer_at_least_t::operator()()` is:

```
  template <typename Error>
  std::size_t operator()(const Error& err, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    return (!!err || bytes_transferred >= minimum_)
      ? 0 : default_max_transfer_size;
  }
```

as you can see 0 is returned if either an error occurred or at least `minimum_` bytes were transferred.

If you know that `read` with `transfer_all` ends when an error occurres, you can *create* this error to see read data. You can shutdown socket (for sending operation) on the server side or just close this socket. Then you can change `read` call to get `error_code` and you should see *End of file* as error:

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
boost::asio::read(socket,response,ec);
if (ec)
{
   cout << ec.message() << endl; // End of file
   // if ec is End of file you can see what data was read into streambuf
}
```

---

You send a serialized object, so you know the size of this object, why not use the approach where you are sending the size of object (for example on 4 bytes) then after this header the content of object is sent later.

At the client side:

```
array<char,4> length;
boost::asio::read(socket,boost::asio::buffer(length));
int contentLen = /*conversion from length array into integer */
vector<char> content( contentLen );
boost::asio::read(socket,boost::asio::buffer(content));
```